# Shellcode crashing target PE

Tags: c, portable-executable, shellcode

I am currently attempting to patch a target `x86` PE file from the disk with a tool, `patch.exe`.

**purpose**

The purpose of this tool will be to eventually write/insert a multi-function payload into the target executable, who's purpose is to track the position of certain frames inside a game which I created.

**background**

I am doing this by mapping the file into memory with `PAGE_READWRITE` protection flag. After locating the RVA of `foobar(...)` function from memory, I am replacing the call to this function with a `JMP (0xE9)` instruction followed by the RVA of the payload shellcode (which is previously appended to a new section I have created within the target PE file beforehand).

When the shellcode simply contains the following bytes

```
unsigned char shellcode[16] = {0x33, 0xc0, 0xc3, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc, 0xcc}
```

which translates to the following C function

```
unsigned long basic_ret() { return 0; }
```

*the target executable successfully executes*

**problem**

however, if I try to include another function (`0xDEADBEEF`) within the code

```
unsigned char shellcode[32] =
{
    0x6a, 0x0b, 0x68, 0x9c, 0xc2, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x6a, 0x0a, 0x68, 0xa8, 0xc2, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x68, 0xb4,
    0xc2, 0xf4, 0x00, 0xb8, 0xef, 0xeb, 0xda, 0xed, 0xff, 0xd0, 0x83, 0xc4, 0x14, 0xc3, 0xcc, 0xcc
};
```

which translates to the following C function (a simple `JMP` taking 3 arguments on the stack, to another function)

```
int simple_jmp()
{
    typedef int (*_jmp_target)(void*, int, void*);
    _jmp_target jmp_target = (_jmp_target) 0xDEADBEEF;

    return jmp_target (0, 5, 0);
}
```

where jmp_target is filled by `patch.exe` with the RVA to a function previously referred to, which was inserted into the new section of the target PE.

When the the target executable is executed, this time, it reaches some type of violation/crash (confirmed by the presence of `WerFault.exe` alongside its execution).

What is the reason for this problem, what am I missing?

**diagnostics**

When I observe the patched bytes in memory (of the mapped PE file), I can see that `0xdeadbeef` is replaced by `0x0dc3f4de` which is the same address from which the inserted function shellcode starts. At this point, I assumed there would be no crash, little to my surprise - crash!

Comment: Since you are mapping code, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE would be a better flag. shellcode2 appears to be passing 5 args (not 3) followed by "mov eax, 0xeddaebef" not 0xdeadbeef.  Assuming you are still replacing the correct "sentinel" value, its unclear if the target is crashing - or are you saying your target is shellcode1?  If you are getting an AV, is the crash dialog reporting a value close to your the replacement (e.g. 0x0dc3f4de) indicating a crash *in* the target?  Try to speckle in some CC's (int3) giving you a chance to attach a debugger just before your sentinel target will execute.